# validates inclusion in Rails not taking action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my Role class looks like this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  rolify :role_cname => 'Permission'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  
  departmentsNames = Institution.find(1).departments
  rolesPrefix = ['super_']
  departmentsNames.each do |departmentsName|
    rolesPrefix.push(departmentsName.department_short)
  end
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  validates :name, inclusion: { in : rolesPrefix, message: "not a valid Role Prefix"}

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true    
  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true
  scopify
end
```

rolesPrefix is: `=> ["super_", "AUG", "CHI", "INN", "NCH", "PAL"]`

but why im still be able to do something like this?

```
role = Role.create(name: "should_not_be_eccepted")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but why im still be able to do something like this?*
>
> ```
> role = Role.create(name: "should_not_be_eccepted")
> ```

The validation is failing. `create` always returns an object, but when validation fails no exception is raised. It just isn't saved. [From the docs...](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create)

> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. ***The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.***

`role.id` should be nil. `role.valid?` should be false. `role.errors.details` should contain the validation error.

---

Get into the habit of using [`create!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21) instead. `create!` will throw an exception on validation error which cannot be ignored. Also `update!` and `save!`.

`create`, `save`, and `update` are appropriate when you need to examine the validation errors. For example, in a controller...

```
  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])
    if @client.save
      redirect_to @client
    else
      # This line overrides the default rendering behavior, which
      # would have been to render the "create" view.
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

The new template can use the validation errors in `@client` to populate its form with instructions about what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: but in my case it still saving no matter if i used create or create!
`=> ["default", "super_admin", "chi_nurse", "test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "should_not_be_eccepted"]`

Comment: @Geogre Please make sure you're showing us your *real code*. What you have in your question has a syntax error. `in : rolesPrefix`, there cannot be a space after `in`.

Comment: thats a little bit embaressing and explains everything. whnerever i fixed the syntax error it works fine.
like what youve written, if i use only create i won't get the message.
thanx for your answer!

Comment: @Geogre Glad you got it fixed. Strange that the code ran with a syntax error. Are you using a preloader like spring?